# Laravel get all value from collection or array

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections

i need ur help

This is information from the form.

[image]

I will rearrange the structure according to the document.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-collapse

This my code

```
$facility = collect($request->facility);
$item = $facility->collapse();
dd($item->all());
```

This my debug 
[image]

Thing I want

facility = [40,39,42,43,44,41,38,2]

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The facility array looks like this. `$request->facility` will return exactly what you want, the picture you show just makes the array "more readable"

Comment: you can get like this: $facility = $request->facility; no need to convert in collection and then collapse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to take any action on this. `$request->facility` will return the array you want. The reason, why the array looks different in your console, is the browser.

`[2,3,4,5]` is equal to

```
[
 0 => 2,
 1 => 3,
 2 => 4,
 3 => 5
]
```

This simply shows the position of the value in the array. Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php)

The `collapse()` method will combine multiple arrays into one:

```
$collection = collect([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]);

$collapsed = $collection->collapse();

$collapsed->all();

// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```